# Hiding suggestion giving by keyboard while typing

Tags: android

Hello 
How to hide spell suggestion of keyboard while typing in a edittext.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use textNoSuggestions with your [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) attribute on the EditText to try hide the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:hint="Enter city "
        />
```

Comment: i tried it but this is not working.I am trying to do like when we type on a edittext then the android keyboard gives the spell suggestion i am trying to do hide those suggestions.